# Python Web Scraping : Split quantities from Unstructured Data

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, data-cleaning

I am relatively new to the field of Web Scraping as well as python. I am trying to scrape data from a supermarket/Online Grocery stores.
I am facing an issue in cleaning the scraped data-
Data Sample Scraped

- Tata Salt Lite, Low Sodium, 1kg
- Fortune Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil,    1L (Pet Bottle)
- Bourbon Bliss, 150g (Buy 3 Get 1 Free) Amazon Brand
- Vedaka Popular Toor/Arhar Dal, 1 kg
- Eno Bottle  100 g (Regular) Pro
- Nature 100% Organic Masoor Black Whole, 500g
- Surf Excel Liquid Detergent  1.05 L

Considering the above data sample I would like to separate the quantities from the product names.
Required Format
Name -Tata Salt Lite, Low Sodium,
Quantity -1kg
Name - Fortune Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil
Quantity - 1L and so on...
I have tried to separate the same with a regex

```
re.split("[,/._-]+", i)
```

but with partial success. 
Could anyone please help me on how to handle the dataset. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share HTML for the same? All text content is located in single node or it's compound node?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement below solution to each string:

```
text_content = "Tata Salt Lite, Low Sodium, 1kg"
quantity = re.search("(\d+\s?(kg|g|L))", text_content).group()
name = text_content.rsplit(quantity)[0].strip().rstrip(',')
description = "Name - {}, Quantity - {}".format(name, quantity)
```

Comment: Hi @Andersson
Sorry for the late response i was Out Of Office.I am trying to iterate it for a field in the data frame like this
for i in df['Name'] :
    quantity = re.search("(\d*\s?(kg|g|L|ml))", i).group()
    name = i.rsplit(quantity)[0].strip().rstrip(',')
and i want to write the separate fields into csv. But above code gives me a error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
Could you please help?

Comment: @PrakharJhudele , That means that regex match nothing... Are you sure that `i` is a string like `"Surf Excel Liquid Detergent 1.05 L"`?

Comment: Brilliant . yes it is working now !! Just checked the variables it was due to a index problem .. .However the majority of records are filtered I just have about 25% of total records. I think due to nature of data?

Comment: @PrakharJhudele Do you mean that my code missed some data or scraped data contain extra text which you don't need or scraped data contains only part of required text? You might need to modify your selectors or modify complete data-scraping code. You haven't shared that code, so it's hard to tell what's wrong

Comment: yes I think I will have to rewrite the scraper code. I thought the data cleaning would be faster but seams the other way around. Anyways thank you so much for your Expertise will need your help soon . :)